# Go To Next Input of BDI ID that contain TEXT Through Jquery

Tags: java, jquery

I am not an IT Professional but i was using some code on a website through Tampermonkey

Website Code:-

```
    <div id="__grid1-wrapperfor-__label44" class="sapUiRespGridSpanL1 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS6 sapUiRespGridSpanXL1">
<span id="__label44" data-sap-ui="__label44" class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable sapMLabelRequired sapMLabelMaxWidth DCA-FormLable" style="text-align: left;">
    <span id="__label44-text" class="sapMLabelTextWrapper">
        <bdi id="__label44-bdi">Truck No</bdi>
</span>
<span data-colon=":" class="sapMLabelColonAndRequired">
</span>
</span>
</div>
<div id="__grid1-wrapperfor-__xmlview3--truckNumber" class="sapUiRespGridSpanL2 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS6 sapUiRespGridSpanXL2">
<div id="__xmlview3--truckNumber" data-sap-ui="__xmlview3--truckNumber" class="sapMInputBase sapMInputBaseHeightMargin sapMInput DCA-FormField" style="width: 100%;"><div id="__xmlview3--truckNumber-content" class="sapMInputBaseContentWrapper" style="width: 100%;">
    <input id="__xmlview3--truckNumber-inner" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="sapMInputBaseInner">
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Earlier Site was Using Label ID instead of BDI id and my script was working very Fine

My Requirement is to change the input id attributes

My earlier Code:-

```
    $("label:contains('Truck No')").parent().next().find('input').attr({
        maxlength: "10",
        Autocomplete: "OFF",
        list: "KASHIPUR",
        Placeholder: "TRUCK NUMBER",
        autocapitalize:"ON"
        }).after('<Datalist ID=KASHIPUR></Datalist>');
```

It stopped working after they changed Label ID to BDI ID

INPUT ID is variable so cannot use input ID

Pls Help.

Comment: You say they changed `label` to `bdi` - did you try making the same change in your code?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes I tried but did not work